# How to cancel the BLE task when the device gets disconnected?

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms, bluetooth-lowenergy

I'm doing BLE implementation in Xamarin forms. I want to stop the BLE tasks when the device get disconnected. I used cancellation token for stopping the task and also gave a call to a void method which has return as you can see in the following code:

```
private async Task ConnectForDevice(ScanData scanData, CancellationTokenSource token)
        {
          
            try
            {
                await _adapter.ConnectToDeviceAsync(_device);
            }
            catch (DeviceConnectionException ex)
            {
              
                
                await UserDialogs.Instance.AlertAsync("Device got disconnected please scan again 2");
                 disconnected();
                token.Cancel();
               
            }
}
 public async void disconnected()
        {
            await Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopAsync();
            return;
            
        }
```

The `token.Cancel()` should stop the task but it doesn't stop the execution. Instead it goes and executes other async tasks. Is there any way to stop these async task easily? Any suggestion?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are using the cancellation token wrong and your code does not make a lot of sense.

First you should have a `CancellationToken` and not a `CancellationTokenSource` as a parameter in `ConnectForDevice` if this is the taks you want to cancel. You create a `CancellationTokenSource` in the class calling `ConnectForDevices` passen the cancellationsource's token to it, being able to cancel the task from the caller by calling `cancellationTaskSource.Cancel()`.

I don't know the API/Library you are using, but I suppose there is an overload for * `_adapter.ConnectToDeviceAsync` getting a `CancellationToken`. There you pass you `cancellationToken`, which when cancelled will cancel the execution.

This will raise an exception of type `TaskCancelledException` (if implemented in so in `_adapter.ConnectToDevice`). I say if implemented, since calling `cancellationTokenSource.Cancel()` will just mark the token for cancellation, setting `IsCancellationRequested=true` but somewhere (normally inside the method to be cancelled) `token. ThrowIfCancellationRequested()` needs to be called or manually checking the state of `IsCancellationRequested` and throwing or cancelling or whatever, in order to stop the execution.

Also I suppose the `ConnectToDeviceAsync` method will only connect to the device and return or throw an exception afterwards. You will get no signaling of a disconnection this way. I also suppose the `DeviceConnectionException` will only raise if an exception when connecting to the device happen, but this does not mean a disconnection, because there was no connection.

Normally there is an event with informs you about this, but can be there is not, so the only way would be polling the connection or sth.

So your code becomes more something like this:

```cs
private async Task ConnectForDevice(ScanData scanData, CancellationToken token)
{
    try
    {
        await _adapter.ConnectToDeviceAsync(_device, token);
    }
    catch (DeviceConnectionException ex)
    {
        await UserDialogs.Instance.AlertAsync("Device got disconnected please scan again 2");
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException tce)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Scan was cancelled");
    }
    finally
    {
        await Disconnect();
    }
}

public Task Disconnect() //NEVER USE ASYNC VOID, ONLY IN EVENT HANDLERS
{
    return Application.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopAsync();
}
```

### Update

You are understanding Plugin.BLE wrong.
Here a basic example (not use in production, is for demo)

```cs
void Main()
{
    //Create your token source
    var tcs = new CancellationTokenSource();
    //Since we dont await execution goes on to demo cancellation
    ScanAndConnectToKnownDevice(/*{yourDeviceId}*/,tcs.Token); 
    Thread.Sleep(2000)
    tcs.Cancel(); //We cancel the process after 2 seconds.
}

async Task ScanAndConnectToKnownDevice(Guid deviceId, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    IDevice device;

    //CrossBluetoothLE.Current.Adapter has a few events to handle connection changes
    //We wire some of them here
    //There is an event for when a device disconnects, which
    //will be raised when ANY device disconnects
    CrossBluetoothLE.Current.Adapter.DeviceDisconnected += OnDeviceDisconnected;
    //There is an event for when a device is discovered in scan
    CrossBluetoothLE.Current.Adapter.DeviceDiscovered += OnDeviceDiscovered;

    //Start scanning process
    try
    {
        await CrossBluetoothLE.Current.Adapter.StartScanningForDevicesAsync(tcs.Token);
    }
    catch (TaskCanceledException tce)
    {
        await UserDialogs.Instance.AlertAsync("Scanning was cancelled");
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        await UserDialogs.Instance.AlertAsync("Error scanning for devices");
    }
    if (device is null)
    {
        await UserDialogs.Instance.AlertAsync("Device not found!");
    }
    else
    {
        try
        {
            //This will ONLY CONNECT to the device and then RETURN after connection
            //The token you are passing here will cancel THE CONNECTION PROCESS, 
            //that does not mean device was disconnected, but that there were problems 
//CONNECTING to the device
            await BluetoothService.ConnectForDevice(device, tcs.Token);
        }
        catch (DeviceConnectionException ex)
        {
            await UserDialogs.Instance.AlertAsync("Error connecting to the device!");           
        }
        catch (TaskCanceledException tce)
        {
            await UserDialogs.Instance.AlertAsync("Connection process was cancelled!");
        }
    }
}

private async void OnDeviceDisconnected(object sender, DeviceEventArgs e) //Is OK to use async void here
{
    if (a.Device.ID == deviceId)
        await UserDialogs.Instance.AlertAsync("Device got disconnected please scan again 2");
}

private void OnDeviceDiscovered(object sender, DeviceEventArgs e) //Is OK to use async void here
{
    if (a.Device.ID == deviceId)
        _device = a.Device;
}
```

Comment: Do I have to add token.Cancel() inside catch (DeviceConnectionException ex)?

Comment: There is indeed not an overload but a default parameter. How OP missed it I don't know: https://github.com/xabre/xamarin-bluetooth-le/blob/9d4ec4d4f718971a1aac0ef8bf986b8bfa492de9/Source/Plugin.BLE.Abstractions/AdapterBase.cs#L95

Comment: My purpose is to show the disconnection alert and stop the execution when the connection is disconnected.

Comment: See my update @JudsonAbraham and please accept it if useful